# Saving UIGraphicsContext image as .png instead of .jpg

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have this code to resize my image into a thumbnail:

```
//MAKE THUMBNAIL

    CGSize origImageSize = chosenImage.size;

    //the rectangle of the thumbnail;
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70);

    //scaling ratio
    float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width/origImageSize.width, newRect.size.height/origImageSize.height);


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);


    CGRect projectRect;
    projectRect.size.width= ratio*origImageSize.width;
    projectRect.size.height=ratio*origImageSize.height;
    //center the image
    projectRect.origin.x= ((newRect.size.width-projectRect.size.width)/2);
    projectRect.origin.y=((newRect.size.height-projectRect.size.height)/2);
    [chosenImage drawInRect:projectRect];

    //get the image from the image context
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.thumbnailView.image=smallImage;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(smallImage, self, nil, nil); //20kb
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

it saves the image as a jpg, is there anyway I can save it as a png instead? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting your image's data to a PNG data representation then back into a PNG image, ex:

```
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *pngImageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);
UIImage *pngSmallImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pngImageData];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngSmallImage, self, nil, nil); //20kb
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: will I lose image quality doing this? Is it better to store images as png or does it not make much difference?

Comment: @Kex Doubt it. PNG supports lossless data compression.